# Rationally nesting functions

Tags: f#

I created a `combine` function that, given a tuple of lists, returns a list of tuples:

```
let rec combine =
fun (l1, l2) ->
    match (l1, l2) with
    | ([], [])          -> []
    | (x::xs, y::ys)    -> (x, y)::(combine xs ys)
```

Then I built a similar function `foo56` that works the same way but with four lists instead of two.

```
let rec foo76 =     //Combine  a 4-tuple of lists in a list of 4-tuples
fun (l1, l2, l3, l4) ->
    match (l1, l2, l3, l4) with
    ([], [], [], [])                ->  []
    | (x::xs, y::ys, z::zs, t::ts)  ->
        (x, y, z, t)::(foo76 (xs, ys, zs, ts))
```

The problem: I would like to implement `foo56` to make it work through `combine`. I did several attempts, failing. Here is the most (sigh) promising:

```
let foo76combine =     //Combine  a 4-tuple of lists in a list of 4-tuples
    fun (l1, l2, l3, l4) ->
        match (l1, l2, l3, l4) with
        ([], [], [], [])                ->  []
        | (x::xs, y::ys, z::zs, t::ts)  ->
            (x, y, z, t)::(combine(combine(combine (xs, ys) zs) ts))
```

I fail to visualize how to properly nest `combine` in itself recursively. It may be due to my inexperience, I suppose. Am I, at least, on the right way? It is not just to make `foo76` work. I am interested to have a better grasp on the practical use of this approach, where I can decompose the problem in smaller parts.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get what you want by simply composing `combine`. The innermost `combine` will work as you expect, yielding an `('a * 'b) list`, but the next one takes an `('a * 'b) list` and a `'c list`, yielding `(('a * 'b) * 'c)) list`, rather than `('a * 'b * 'c) list` that you'd want to see.

Tuples simply don't work that way - you can't generalize to a "tuple of arbitrary length". That's why there are separate `List.zip` and `List.zip3` functions, rather than a general `List.zipN`. If you want to handle different tuple sizes, you need different and separate functions for them.

You can compensate for that somewhat, by mapping the resulting "nested" tuple to a 4-tuple, but what you get for reusing `combine` is not worth the hassle in my opinion - it's both harder to read and less performant compared to a dedicated function like `foo76`:

```
let rec zip4 (l1, l2, l3, l4) =
    match l1, l2, l3, l4 with
    | [], [], [], []              ->  []
    | x::xs, y::ys, z::zs, t::ts  ->
        (x, y, z, t) ::
            (List.map
                (fun (((a,b),c),d) -> (a,b,c,d))
                (combine(combine(combine(xs, ys), zs), ts)))
```

Comment: That's a very good point. I will sometime doing a little of practice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`List.zip` is an existing function that is similar to your `combine` function. There is a `List.zip3` too, which takes 3 lists, but there is no built-in `List.zip4`. You could define it yourself in terms of `List.zip` like this:

```
let zip4 a b c d =
    a
    |> List.zip b
    |> List.zip c
    |> List.zip d
    |> List.map (fun (d, (c, (b, a))) -> (a, b, c, d))
```